# How to delay the content loading with Telerik MVC Window until it is visible?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc

```
    WindowBuilder dialog = Html.Telerik().Window().Name("win")
        .Visible(false)
        .Modal(true)
        .LoadContentFrom("someaction", "somecontroller");

    dialog.Render();
```

The previous code causes the window to load the content when the containing page is loaded. Is there a way to delay the content from loading until it is visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to manually load the content; listen for an event: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/window/clientsideevents and append the content to the window's inner element (not sure if there is a property where you can set the HTML...).